# Linking to homepage with EasyPHP Devserver

Tags: html, .htaccess, easyphp

I'm trying to have a link return to the homepage of my site, which usually can be accomplished with the following:

```
<a href="/">Link Here</a>
```

However, when I try to do this on Devserver, it takes me back one step too far, and when I put nothing in the `href` like

```
<a href="">Link Here</a>
```

It only refreshes the page. I could just link it to `index` as I have an .htaccess file already, but I'd rather it just went back to the DirectoryIndex with nothing else in the URL.

Comment: What is the absolute URL of your homepage?